# Can substrate be used for non-currency applications?

Tags: blockchain, substrate

My team and I are trying to create a blockchain based simple database to catalogue information found on the web. This is just a proof of concept for a company private blockchain and right now we want to use it to store four fields:

1. Document hash
2. Date
3. URL
4. Title

We don't want a ledger or any kind of currency features. We simply want to build a private blockchain node network that stores these simple fields. Can I build a pallet that will do this or am I confused as to what substrate is meant for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding private network look at the [tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/alicebob).